# How to display newLines <br /> using react-i18next

Tags: reactjs, typescript, translation, i18next, react-i18next

Hi everyone i'm having a lot of trouble using the react-i18next@11.15.3 to insert the html tag <br /> to break lines instead of having multiple keys for each line of the paragraph

i have done everything that is said on the documentation and it does not seems to work, also i have seen other questions and tried their solutions but it seems that it doesn't work for me, for some reason.

my config is this:

```
i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    lng: 'en',
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
    react: {
      useSuspense: false,
      transSupportBasicHtmlNodes: true,
      transKeepBasicHtmlNodesFor: ['br', 'strong', 'i', 'p'],
    },
  });
```

And i have something like this on my translation file:

```
{
  "members": {
    "upsert": {
      "info": "Use this feature to add users to your organization. <newline/> <newline/> After an user is added to the organization it will be possible to invite them to specific applications."
    }
  }
}
```

And how i render it:

```
<Trans
          i18nKey={'members.upsert.info'}
          components={{ newline: <br /> }}
        ></Trans>
```

i have tried different approaches, using numbered elements and a array in the component props, using {{var_name}}, to substitute it, even using directly the 
 tag but nothing seems to work, if anyone have an idea of what can be the issue here it would be really helpful, thanks in advance